# Flutter Post request giving Error _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, post

When Encoding the body to JSON I am getting this error _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast). The data I'm trying to encode is a simple object

```
{
   "visitor": {
        "token": <some string UUID>
   }
}
```

I have tried just submitting a string for the visitor value and it at least doesn't error out but my API requires a visitor object in order for the post to be successful. This is the code I'm using

```
Future<String> registerVisitor() async {
    try {
      var newID = Uuid().v4();
      final req = {
        'visitor': {
          'token': newID
        }
      };
      var response = await http.post(
        _rocketChatRegisterVisitorUrl,
        body: req,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return newID;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
        throw "An Error Has Occured when registering visitor";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding your Map with `jsonEncode` will fix your problem :

```
Future<String> registerVisitor() async {
    try {
      var newID = Uuid().v4();
      final req = {
        'visitor': {
          'token': newID
        }
      };
      var response = await http.post(
        _rocketChatRegisterVisitorUrl,
        body: jsonEncode(req),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return newID;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
        throw "An Error Has Occured when registering visitor";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```